# Extend table to more than one page so I can record everyday data in same pdf?

Tags: tables

I am writing a four column table of my everyday activities as asked by my doctor. Currently I made five blocks of 13,14,15,16 and 17 august, but I will have to then add more after next session on 18th. But the thing is, this table is not going any further than first page. That is pdf is putting everything from top in one page and then everything else is lost on pdf, why can't there be page 2, page 3 and so on...?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h]

\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|  }
 \hline
 
 \textbf{What came to mind?} & \textbf{Situation behind it} &\textbf{Thoughts about it}&\textit{Feelings about it}\\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{13 August 2021 - Friday} \\
 \hline
 10:40 a.m.- I should keep virtual diary instead of physical one. It makes me feel more safe and I can write more stuff here and truths instead of the physical one.   & fgh  & I think it will improve the recordings and will result in a better data. &  Feel good about this decision.\\
 \hline
 9:00 p.m. -  Nothing else to record. &   xyz.  & I think there is nothing wrong & But I feel that this might result in something \\
 \hline
10:30 p.m. potato & tomato & okra &  zucchini \\

 \hline
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{14 August 2021- Saturday} \\
 \hline
 
12:15 p.m. Felt anxiety more than ususal.    & May be lack of sleep last night   & It happens sometimes, no big deal. &   Where is Waldo?\\
 \hline
 x&   X  & AA   &123\\
 \hline
 x & L & B&  321\\
 \hline
 z    &Z & A&  000\\

 \hline
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{15 August 2021 - Sunday} \\
 \hline
 
 GG   & AF    &AG&   007\\
 \hline
 x&   X  & AA   &123\\
 \hline
 x & L & B&  321\\
 \hline
 z    &Z & A&  000\\

 \hline
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{16 August 2021 - Monday} \\
 \hline
 
 GG   & AF    &AG&   007\\
 \hline
 x&   X  & AA   &123\\
 \hline
 x & L & B&  321\\
 \hline
 z    &Z & A&  000\\

 
 \hline
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{17 August 2021 - Tuesday} \\
 \hline

GG   & AF    &AG&   007\\
 \hline
 x&   X  & AA   &123\\
 \hline
 x & L & B&  321\\
 \hline
 z    &Z & A&  000\\

 \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I am also told to keep separate diary for which I am using '\documentclass{tufte-book}' and it does not pose any problem. How can I fix this table thing to go on for as many pages as I want, or will I have to make a separate tex file for every date?

Comment: If you want to keep the approach of one `tabular` per day, simply remove the `table` environment. You don't need it here. If you on the other hand want to use a single environment for all entries, remove the `table` environment and use a single `longtable` environment instead of the `tabular`s. (Needs the `longtable` package).

Comment: as you want  to allow page breaks between days but not in a day easiest is simply to delete `\begin{table}[h]` and `\end{table}` here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks.